# Apache httpclient javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to connect to a service with SSLv3 security.

The communication works with curl and browser after providing the following files

```
1. ca.crt
2. private.key
2. client.crt
```

I used all the 3 files to create an ssl keystore  with following cmd

```
openssl  pkcs12 -export  -in client.crt  -inkey private.key  -CAfile ca.crt  -out sslstore.p12
```

And then used keytool to import it as java truststore

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore sslstore.p12  -srcstoretype PKCS12  -destkeystore truststore.jks
```

After than I am followed the following link https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java 
to connect to the url. Only changing the protocol from TLSv1 to SSLv3.

I always get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: excdption while connecting.

As already mentioned the keys work with curl / browser.

*EDIT-2*
Changing the code near SSLContexts.custom()

from:

```
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()                        
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();
```

to:

```
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();
```

worked. Note that I am using the same keystore.

*EDIT-1*
Code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, FileNotFoundException {


        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        InputStream is  = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("certs/ppro.jks");

        try {
            keyStore.load(is,"changeit".toCharArray());
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
        SSLContext sslcontext = null;
        try {
            sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sslcontext.loadKeyMaterial(keyStore,"changeit".toCharArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext,
                new String[] { "SSLv3" } ,
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .build()) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
            try {

                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println(response);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

*EDIT-0*

Here is the stacktrace from java  including some ssl debug info.

```
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, SSLv3
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 132
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 00 E7 89 C2 9D AB 1A   3B 75 85 5B 4E C6 EE 10  ........;u.[N...
0010: 83 0F 3C 37 74 3C D0 6A   AF 51 D7 EC E2 B9 50 35  ..<7t<.j.Q....P5
0020: CC 8D 58 93 39 5D B6 4F   BE DB 5A F4 E3 0A BE 42  ..X.9].O..Z....B
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 53 47 9A BD 4B 14 BC AF   B0 2B FB 6C 49 9C E4 53  SG..K....+.lI..S
0010: 21 F3 53 C8 7F 74 1C 5C   C0 5E 6D 67 18 50 10 4D  !.S..t.\.^mg.P.M
Server Nonce:
0000: 53 47 9A BD B2 5C 44 89   92 BE 4B FF F4 F6 60 FE  SG...\D...K...`.
0010: D6 18 67 96 6A 13 3C 80   9F D2 56 29 1A 60 B4 E4  ..g.j.<...V).`..
Master Secret:
0000: E3 E5 11 9F 87 B6 A3 4E   8C 9C F1 20 E9 A5 50 62  .......N... ..Pb
0010: DD E8 E6 A3 61 FC C0 56   0C 1E A8 29 BC F4 5C 52  ....a..V...)..\R
0020: DE CE 98 64 0E 57 07 E6   22 24 08 1A 77 8A 97 48  ...d.W.."$..w..H
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 44 98 8B 9C C4 59 C2 4E   21 66 67 6D 96 C4 FE 9C  D....Y.N!fgm....
0010: 2B 74 AD 61                                        +t.a
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 29 7D 5A F2 71 B6 55 C0   CF BB 82 66 02 03 B1 35  ).Z.q.U....f...5
0010: 5A 69 83 99                                        Zi..
Client write key:
0000: B5 32 F7 7C DC DB 4F B4   00 48 66 A4 B3 C0 7D 6B  .2....O..Hf....k
Server write key:
0000: CB 80 F4 76 53 92 6F 87   3B A3 9D B2 A9 6F 40 85  ...vS.o.;....o@.
Client write IV:
0000: B7 89 4A FC 43 7A 1B 3C   DD 83 7F CE A1 FC FB BF  ..J.Cz.<........
Server write IV:
0000: 84 92 B7 B4 EB 13 B6 77   EF 87 B0 E1 04 41 5C 4D  .......w.....A\M
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 116, 66, 54, 146, 216, 200, 254, 221, 170, 236, 204, 2, 17, 139, 161, 37, 205, 117, 131, 95, 255, 123, 158, 100, 150, 110, 105, 209, 22, 205, 31, 196, 95, 84, 59, 252 }
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 64
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.masterpayment.frontend.gateway.beconnector.GiroGateClient.main(GiroGateClient.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
main, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache example only sets up a trust store.  That will only use the CA cert.  You need to also set up an "identity" for handling the client certificate.  I realize you put them all in the same java keystore, and that is *probably* still okay (but normally they are in separate files).

The example calls loadTrustMaterial().  You also need to call loadKeyMaterial().

Comment: can you provide an example or a link to one ?  How do I create an Identity ?

Comment: It looks like you've already created an identity.  You just happened to have put it in the same keystore with CA certs.  Please post your code around SSLContexts.custom()

Comment: I changed the code around SSLContexts.custom() to sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that you're getting a PKIX chain verficiation error - try the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 \
    -export \
    -chain \
    -in client.crt \
    -inkey private.key \
    -CAfile ca.crt \
    -out sslstore.p12
```

Note the above - I have added the '-chain' option - this should properly export the certificate into the PKCS#12 archive with the appropriate certificate chaining.

I've run into this more times than I can count in the past 6 mos and it always gets me.

If this does not work, please add some of your stack trace from Java as well.

Comment: I tried it. This time I got javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: error. I have already imported ca.crt into $JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: This happens until I import the ca.crt in the truststore. After importing I get the exception mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Ugh i hate vagueness of that exception. I'd like to try to proof this out locally, can you tell me which version you are using

Comment: I am using 4.3.3 of apche httpclient